# Dart: How to test if stream emits elements at a certain time?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, stream, dart

I try to test a function `Stream transform(Stream input)`. How can I test if the returned stream emits elements at a certain time?

In [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) (JavaScript) I can use a [TestScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md) to emit elements on the input stream at a certain time and test if they are emitted on the output stream at a certain time. In this [example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md#example), the transform function is passed to `scheduler.startWithCreate`:

```js
var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();

// Create hot observable which will start firing
var xs = scheduler.createHotObservable(
  onNext(150, 1),
  onNext(210, 2),
  onNext(220, 3),
  onCompleted(230)
);

// Note we'll start at 200 for subscribe, hence missing the 150 mark
var res = scheduler.startWithCreate(function () {
  return xs.map(function (x) { return x * x });
});

// Implement collection assertion
collectionAssert.assertEqual(res.messages, [
  onNext(210, 4),
  onNext(220, 9),
  onCompleted(230)
]);

// Check for subscribe/unsubscribe
collectionAssert.assertEqual(xs.subscriptions, [
  subscribe(200, 230)
]);
```

Comment: What do you need this for? Are `150`, `210`, `220`, ..., milliseconds? How much deviation is acceptable? Checking the events arrive in a specific order is an obvious requirement but there aren't any timing guarantees in async processing. I didn't have a closer look at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scheduled_test. Maybe it contains something you are looking for.

Comment: I'd like to test if stream values are delayed correctly. Deviation depends on the delay. `150`, `210`, `220`, ..., can be assumed to be milliseconds in the example. Actually, TestScheduler simulates time. Thus, the test does not last this time. Thereby, you can even test delays of an hour in a second.

Comment: You can't fake time in Dart the same way you can in JS because you can't overwrite the `DateTime.now` or `Stopwatch` constructors. Your program can always get the correct time if it wants to. You can intercept timers using a `Zone`, but that will only help you so much. As for checking streams, the way to test when they output something is to listen to the stream and check when you get an event, I don't think it has to be any fancier than that. I always agree with Günther Zöchbauer that expecting exact timing is not safe, you can be delayed arbitrarily long by any other executing code.

Comment: I feared that. In that case, a deviation of 10 milliseconds should be acceptable. How can I test if a stream element is emitted in a certain time window?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Released my code as a package called [stream_test_scheduler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_test_scheduler).

This code works similar to [TestScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md) in [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), but it uses real time (milliseconds) instead of virtual time, since you can't fake time in Dart (see [Irn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345853/dart-how-to-test-if-stream-emits-elements-at-a-certain-time#comment52575633_32345853)). You can pass a maximum deviation to the matcher. I use 20 milliseconds in this example. But deviation varies. You might have to use a different maximum deviation value for another test or on another (faster/slower) system.

**Edit:** I changed the example to a delay transform function, which is a shorter (less configurable/parameters) version of the [delay](https://github.com/theburningmonk/stream_ext/wiki/delay) function of [stream_ext](https://github.com/theburningmonk/stream_ext) package. The test checks if elements are delayed by one second.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:test/test.dart';

// To test:
/// Modified version of <https://github.com/theburningmonk/stream_ext/wiki/delay>
Stream delay(Stream input, Duration duration) {
  var controller = new StreamController.broadcast(sync : true);
  delayCall(Function f, [Iterable args]) => args == null
      ? new Timer(duration, f)
      : new Timer(duration, () => Function.apply(f, args));
  input.listen(
      (x) => delayCall(_tryAdd, [controller, x]),
      onError : (ex) => delayCall(_tryAddError, [ex]),
      onDone  : () => delayCall(_tryClose, [controller])
  );
  return controller.stream;
}

_tryAdd(StreamController controller, event) {
  if (!controller.isClosed) controller.add(event);
}

_tryAddError(StreamController controller, err) {
  if (!controller.isClosed) controller.addError(err);
}

_tryClose(StreamController controller) {
  if (!controller.isClosed) controller.close();
}

main() async {
  test('delay preserves relative time intervals between the values', () async {
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var source = scheduler.createStream([
      onNext(150, 1),
      onNext(210, 2),
      onNext(220, 3),
      onCompleted(230)
    ]);

    var result = await scheduler.startWithCreate(() => delay(source, ms(1000)));

    expect(result, equalsRecords([
      onNext(1150, 1),
      onNext(1210, 2),
      onNext(1220, 3),
      onCompleted(1230)
    ], maxDeviation: 20));
  });
}

equalsRecords(List<Record> records, {int maxDeviation: 0}) {
  return pairwiseCompare(records, (Record r1, Record r2) {
    var deviation = (r1.ticks.inMilliseconds - r2.ticks.inMilliseconds).abs();
    if (deviation > maxDeviation) {
      return false;
    }
    if (r1 is OnNextRecord && r2 is OnNextRecord) {
      return r1.value == r2.value;
    }
    if (r1 is OnErrorRecord && r2 is OnErrorRecord) {
      return r1.exception == r2.exception;
    }
    return (r1 is OnCompletedRecord && r2 is OnCompletedRecord);
  }, 'equal with deviation of ${maxDeviation}ms to');
}

class TestScheduler {
  final SchedulerTasks _tasks;

  TestScheduler() : _tasks = new SchedulerTasks();

  Stream createStream(List<Record> records) {
    final controller = new StreamController(sync: true);
    _tasks.add(controller, records);
    return controller.stream;
  }

  Future<List<Record>> startWithCreate(Stream createStream()) {
    final completer = new Completer<List<Record>>();
    final records = <Record>[];
    final start = new DateTime.now();
    int timeStamp() {
      final current = new DateTime.now();
      return current.difference(start).inMilliseconds;
    }
    createStream().listen(
      (event) => records.add(onNext(timeStamp(), event)),
      onError: (exception) => records.add(onError(timeStamp(), exception)),
      onDone: () {
        records.add(onCompleted(timeStamp()));
        completer.complete(records);
      }
    );
    _tasks.run();
    return completer.future;
  }
}

class SchedulerTasks {
  Map<Record, StreamController> _controllers = {};
  List<Record> _records = [];

  void add(StreamController controller, List<Record> records) {
    for (var record in records) {
      _controllers[record] = controller;
    }
    _records.addAll(records);
  }

  void run() {
    _records.sort();
    for (var record in _records) {
      final controller = _controllers[record];
      new Future.delayed(record.ticks, () {
        if (record is OnNextRecord) {
          controller.add(record.value);
        } else if (record is OnErrorRecord) {
          controller.addError(record.exception);
        } else if (record is OnCompletedRecord) {
          controller.close();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

onNext(int ticks, int value) => new OnNextRecord(ms(ticks), value);

onCompleted(int ticks) => new OnCompletedRecord(ms(ticks));

onError(int ticks, exception) => new OnErrorRecord(ms(ticks), exception);

Duration ms(int milliseconds) => new Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);

abstract class Record implements Comparable {
  final Duration ticks;
  Record(this.ticks);

  @override
  int compareTo(other) => ticks.compareTo(other.ticks);
}

class OnNextRecord extends Record {
  final value;
  OnNextRecord(Duration ticks, this.value) : super (ticks);

  @override
  String toString() => 'onNext($value)@${ticks.inMilliseconds}';
}

class OnErrorRecord extends Record {
  final exception;
  OnErrorRecord(Duration ticks, this.exception) : super (ticks);

  @override
  String toString() => 'onError($exception)@${ticks.inMilliseconds}';
}

class OnCompletedRecord extends Record {
  OnCompletedRecord(Duration ticks) : super (ticks);

  @override
  String toString() => 'onCompleted()@${ticks.inMilliseconds}';
}
```